# DSP libraries - RFFT - strange results

Tags: c, arm, fft, cortex-m

Recently I've been trying to do FFT calculations on my STM32F4-Discovery evaluation board then send it to PC. I have looked into my problem - I think that I'm doing something wrong with FFT functions provided by manufacturer.

I'm using CMSIS-DSP libraries.
For now I've have been generating samples with code (if that works correct I'll do sampling by microphone).

I'm using **`arm_rfft_fast_f32`** as my data are going to be floats in the future, but results I get in my output array are insane (I think) - I'm getting frequencies below 0.

```
number_of_samples = 512; (l_probek in code)
dt = 1/freq/number_of_samples
```

Here is my code

```
float32_t buffer_input[l_probek];
uint16_t i;
uint8_t mode;
float32_t dt;
float32_t freq;
bool DoFlag = false;
bool UBFlag = false;
uint32_t rozmiar = 4*l_probek;

union
{
    float32_t f[l_probek];
    uint8_t b[4*l_probek];
}data_out;


union
{
    float32_t f[l_probek];
    uint8_t b[4*l_probek];
}data_mag;

union
{
    float32_t f;
    uint8_t b[4];
}czest_rozdz;


/* Pointers ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
arm_rfft_fast_instance_f32 S;
arm_cfft_radix4_instance_f32 S_CFFT;
uint16_t output;
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main(void)
{
    freq = 5000;
    dt = 0.000000390625;


    _GPIO();
    _LED();
    _NVIC();    
    _EXTI(0);

    arm_rfft_fast_init_f32(&S, l_probek);
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, LED_Green);

    mode = 2;


    //----------------- Infinite loop
  while (1)
    {
        if(true)//(UBFlag == true)

                    for(i=0; i<l_probek; ++i)
                    {
                        buffer_input[i] = (float32_t) 15*sin(2*PI*freq*i*dt);
                    }

            //Obliczanie FFT
            arm_rfft_fast_f32(&S, buffer_input, data_out.f, 0);
            //Obliczanie modulow
            arm_cmplx_mag_f32(data_out.f, data_mag.f, l_probek);

            USART_putdata(USART1, data_out.b, data_mag.b, rozmiar);
            //USART_putdata(USART1, czest_rozdz.b, data_mag.b, rozmiar);
            GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOD, LED_Orange);
            //mode++;
            //UBFlag = false;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that your input samples are correct for your test?  Also, what is the value of l_probek? Is it 512?

Comment: @DaveS He seems to be calculating on a test sine wave in `buffer_input`.

Comment: Regarding this line - How did you determine the amplitude of 15?  buffer_input[i] = (float32_t) 15*sin(2*PI*freq*i*dt);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm using **`arm_rfft_fast_f32`** as my data are going to be floats in the future, but results I get in my output array are insane (I think) - I'm getting frequencies below 0.

The [`arm_rfft_fast_f32`](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__RealFFT.html#ga180d8b764d59cbb85d37a2d5f7cd9799) function does not return frequencies, but rather complex-valued coefficients computed using the [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). It is thus perfectly reasonable for those coefficients to be negative. More specifically, the expected coefficients for your single-cycle `sin` test tone input with an amplitude of 15 would be:

```
0.0,     0.0; // special case packing real-valued X[0] and X[N/2]
0.0, -3840.0; // X[1]
0.0,     0.0; // X[2]
0.0,     0.0; // X[3]
...
0.0,     0.0; // X[255]
```

Note that as indicated in the [documentation](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__RealFFT.html#details) the first two outputs correspond to the purely real coefficients `X[0]` and `X[N/2]` (you should be particularly careful about this special case in your subsequent call to `arm_cmplx_mag_f32`; see last point below).

The frequency of each of those frequency components are given by `k*fs/N`, where `N` is the number of samples (in your case `l_probek`) and `fs = 1/dt` is the sampling rate (in your case `freq*l_probek`):

```
X[0] -> 0*freq*l_probek/l_probek =              0
X[1] -> 1*freq*l_probek/l_probek =   freq =  5000
X[2] -> 2*freq*l_probek/l_probek = 2*freq = 10000
X[3] -> 3*freq*l_probek/l_probek = 2*freq = 15000
...
```

Finally, due to the special packing of the first two values, you need to be careful when computing the `N/2+1` magnitudes:

```
// General case for the magnitudes
arm_cmplx_mag_f32(data_out.f+2, data_mag.f+1, l_probek/2 - 1);
// Handle special cases
data_mag.f[0]          = data_out.f[0];
data_mag.f[l_probek/2] = data_out.f[1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much SleuthEye. Damn I start to think I'm brainless being ;)
Also I have screwed generating samples for my FFT.
Took wrong **dt** to frequency I have choosen.
Also this morning I have checked that it would be wiser to use **sinf** function to generate values.

Comment: I've got one more question to you - is it normal, that after I call
`arm_rfft_fast_f3` function my input array gets changed?

Comment: Yes, in short that's how that function works. The longer answer is that `arm_rfft_fast_f32` makes use of [`arm_cfft_f32`](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__ComplexFFT.html#gade0f9c4ff157b6b9c72a1eafd86ebf80) which does an in-place computation using the input buffer (thus modifying the input).

Comment: One more thing - are CORTEX-M4 (like stm32F4) uC little-endian or big-endian by default?

Comment: I believe the [user manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/6c/3a/cb/e7/e4/ea/44/9b/DM00046982.pdf/files/DM00046982.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00046982.pdf) mentions little-endian memory access. See also [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/96380).

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to the above answer, which is awesome, some further clarifications which took me an age to figure out.

- The frequency bins are centered on the target frequency, so for instance in the example above X[0] represents -2500Hz to 2500Hz, centered on zero, X[1] is 2500Hz to 7500Hz centered on 5000Hz and so on
- It's common to interpolate frequencies within the bin by looking at the energy of the adjacent bins (see https://dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-interpolate-fft-peak/) if you do this you will need to make sure that your magnitude array is large enough for the bins + Nyquist and that the bin above Nyquist is 0, but note many interpolation techniques require the *complex values* (e.q. Quinn, Jacobson) so make sure you interpolate before finding the magnitudes.
- The special case code above works because there is no complex component of the DC and Nyquist values and thus the magnitude is simply the real part
- There is a bug in the code above however - although the imaginary parts of the DC and Nyquist components is always zero, the real part could still be negative, so you need to take the absolute value to get the magnitude:

```
// Handle special cases
data_mag.f[0]          = fabs(data_out.f[0]);
data_mag.f[l_probek/2] = fabs(data_out.f[1]);
```